# Accessing surveillance camera in VM

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware, camera, vmware-player

I downloaded Ubuntu 17 to run in a VM (VMWare player) on a WIN10 host to be able to test Linux video surveillance camera software. I can ping my gateway and one of the cameras (.155 below) but I can't connect to the camera with either VLC or Xeoma. Suggestions?

```
$ ifconfig -a
ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.168  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::2ea6:4027:a9b2:e030  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:35:f6:01  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 38357  bytes 51867963 (51.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17366  bytes 1391196 (1.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 54577  bytes 7823272 (7.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 54577  bytes 7823272 (7.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ ping 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.12 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=5.18 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=1.56 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.29 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=1.33 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=1.23 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=1.27 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.234/2.144/5.183/1.388 ms
lew@ubuntu:~$ ping 192.168.1.155
PING 192.168.1.155 (192.168.1.155) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.155: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=3.47 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.155: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=10.6 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.155: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=4.16 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.155: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=4.59 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.155: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=7.68 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.155: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=3.36 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.155: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=5.33 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.155 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6009ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 3.360/5.609/10.648/2.466 ms
lew@ubuntu:~$ ping www.ibm.com
PING e2874.dscx.akamaiedge.net (104.96.227.152) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from a104-96-227-152.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.96.227.152): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=38.5 ms
64 bytes from a104-96-227-152.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.96.227.152): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=41.3 ms
64 bytes from a104-96-227-152.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.96.227.152): icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=38.6 ms
64 bytes from a104-96-227-152.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.96.227.152): icmp_seq=4 ttl=54 time=37.7 ms
64 bytes from a104-96-227-152.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.96.227.152): icmp_seq=5 ttl=54 time=38.2 ms
64 bytes from a104-96-227-152.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.96.227.152): icmp_seq=6 ttl=54 time=36.6 ms
^C
--- e2874.dscx.akamaiedge.net ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5117ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 36.685/38.538/41.348/1.440 ms
```

Comment: It may be worth to [edit] the question with the exact make of that camera. Somebody with a similar hardware may then be better at finding the issue.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the drivers for the surveillance camera, try to install the drivers for it in your Windows 10 host. Then, connect the USB (or whatever kind of connection you use) to your Ubuntu 17 guest from the USB icon or from the settings. I'm not sure if this is correct or right. Contact me for more.

Bajiru :)

Comment: OP is using an IP (Internet protocol) camera connected through the local area network.

Comment: correct, I am using a IP camera...also I can view the video stream on the WIN10 host.

Comment: @LewGoins I'm glad you found my answer useful. The possible cause might be that your Ubuntu 17.04 VM guest cannot view the video stream because VMWare Player might not have the appropriate drivers.